# How to install zend framework 1.12.9 in xampp?

Tags: zend-framework

Hy i am new in zend framework and want to install it please tell me how to install in window 7 with xampp server step by step?

Comment: ya i follow this but still have a problum?

Comment: when i giving a path in cmd prompt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

•   Go to ‘My Computer’ > Properties > Advanced Tab > Environment Variables. Environment Variables box will open, View SYSTEM VARIABLES, scroll the list to ’ PATH ‘ > double click ’ PATH ‘ . Add the following line to the end of the PATH  C:\xampp\php
Zend Framework
•   Extract the Zend Framework files to C:\xampp\php\zf.
•   Edit the php.ini file. You will find it at C:\xampp\php\php.ini. 
Find the line that says ’ include_path ’ and edit the line: 
Windows: “\path1;\path2″
include_path = “C:\xampp\php\zf\library”
•   Open a shell and cd to C:\xampp\htdocs folder and type this:
C:\xampp\htdocs>C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\bin\zf.bat create project testproject(project name)

•   Now Copy the Zend Folder from your ZendFramework folder ( C:\xampp\php\zf/library/Zend) into the library folder of your new test project ( C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject\library\Zend

Comment: The inconsistent punctuation and layout of this answer make it hard to do.  This didn't work for me.  Can you layout steps more clearly?